# S3 bucket size differs while using console and CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get my S3 bucket size. I have tried both the console method and CLI method. But, I am getting 19.6 GB from CLI output and 21.3 GB from console.

For console method, I go to s3 bucket => Management Tab => Metrics and see there.

For CLI method, I have entered the following command: aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name --recursive --human-readable --summarize

In which output, should I rely on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is interesting!

I have a bucket with three objects. When I use `aws s3 ls`, it shows the sizes as: (listing has been shortened to show relevant parts only)

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket

foo1 2B
foo2 956.9 KiB
foo3 7.7 KiB


$ aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket --summarize
foo1          2
foo2     979820
foo3       7864

Total Size: 987686


$ aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket --summarize --human-readable

foo1    2 Bytes
foo2  956.9 KiB
foo3    7.7 KiB

Total Objects: 3
   Total Size: 964.5 KiB
```

Note that `964.5 * 1024 = 987,648`, so that's effectively the same.

The listing in the Amazon S3 management console matches the first listing.

In **Amazon CloudWatch**, the metric is provided as `988k`, which seems to be **a rounding of the decimal version** (987,686). So, it is using 1k=1000 instead of 1k=1024. This is good for a generalized metric (eg number of requests), but does not match the convention of memory and disk, which normally uses 1024. (For some history, see: [Wikipedia - Kibibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte)

Another thing to consider is that some metrics **might be including multiple versions** (normally only the latest version of an object appears in a listing) and [incomplete multi-part uploads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html) that are not listed as objects. This could lead to a discrepancy when listing objects, yet they still occupy space. You can [create some lifecycle rules](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-lifecycle-management-update-support-for-multipart-uploads-and-delete-markers/) to clean up multi-part uploads.

Comment: I want to know if AWS generate bills according to 1K=1000 or 1K=1024? Any idea John?

Comment: I'm not sure. The Amazon S3 pricing page says "per GB", so you should assume a worst-case of 1K = 1000 Bytes. The [Amazon EBS pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/) specifically says "on this page GB = 1024^3 bytes".

Answer (score 1):

Your CLI approach output can also be found **from the AWS console** as follows: From the console, you can get the same output by trying out this approach. **Select all objects in the S3 bucket** and under actions, select **Get Total Size**.

Although there are many other good solutions like `s3cmd du`, **the calculating approaches would be slower** either via CLI or AWS console as **in case of large buckets**.

I would recommend that you should **rely on calculating approach as it is going to give more precise value but prefer AWS console output via CloudWatch metric** that is under management tab **if you want to save calculation time** as you don't have to calculate the size of the S3 bucket on your own **but bucket shouldn't have either incomplete multi-part uploads or versioned objects** as they might be included in the metric value as well.